# how to narrow down search results with mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm running big search querys such as:

```
WHERE
 'gender' LIKE '%a%'
 OR fname LIKE '%a%'
 OR mname LIKE '%a%'
 OR lname LIKE '%a%'
 OR address LIKE '%a%'
 OR card LIKE '%a%'
 OR email LIKE '%a%'
 OR fname LIKE '%ryan%'
 OR mname LIKE '%ryan%'
 OR lname LIKE '%ryan%'
 OR address LIKE '%ryan%'
 OR card LIKE '%ryan%'
 OR email LIKE '%ryan%'`
```

It searchs though all this based on what you place in the search box.

mysql would give me the following rows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZSaS.png

```
Ryan Anthony Okeefe
John Albert Doe
Beau Jacob Diddly
Anthony Quinn Jims
Brooke Wame Gagne
```

Heres my problem. I want to get only the most accurate result for this because this. in this case it would be the first result, for the first name is Ryan and it contains the letter a in the first and middle name. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Why can't you just check for `fname = 'Ryan'` then?

Comment: why ryan? how do you want to order the result?

Comment: Because this is a searchbox that people use to find a variaty of things.

I want to order it by most relative. so if i put in 'ant ryan' It would give me 'Ryan Anthony' because of the first and middle name both containing at least one of the entrys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be too efficient, but you could try with:

```
ORDER BY
  (gender LIKE '%a%') +
  (fname LIKE '%a%') +
  (mname LIKE '%a%') +
  (lname LIKE '%a%') +
  (address LIKE '%a%') +
  (card LIKE '%a%') +
  (email LIKE '%a%') +
  (fname LIKE '%ryan%') +
  (mname LIKE '%ryan%') +
  (lname LIKE '%ryan%') +
  (address LIKE '%ryan%') +
  (card LIKE '%ryan%') +
  (email LIKE '%ryan%'`) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

however, I would investigate on [Full Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: fixed a typo you had a `'` after gender, nice solution but the OP has to follow your advice and use FULLTEXT or the server will be on fire :).